# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(HomeScreen)". Either wrap the root component in a... or pass a custom React context provider

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Check multitude of questioned already asked and but still can't figure this one out.

We are rewriting our authentication layer using

```
export default AuthContext = React.createContext();
```

and wrapping it around our AppNavigator

```
function AppNavigator(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(accountReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      loadUser: async () => {
        const token = await keychainStorage.getItem("token");

        if (token) {
          await dispatch({ type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, token: token });
        }
  },

  signIn: async (data) => {
    client
      .post(LOGIN_CUSTOMER_RESOURCE, data)
      .then((res) => {
        const token = res.data.accessToken;
        keychainStorage.setItem("token", token);

        dispatch({ type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, token: token });
      })
      .catch((x) => {
        dispatch({ type: SIGN_IN_FAIL  });
      });
  },

  signOut: () => {
    client.delete({
          LOGOUT_CUSTOMER_RESOURCE
        });

        dispatch({ type: SIGN_OUT_SUCCESS });
      }
    }),
    []
  );
  console.log("token start", state.token);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer
        theme={MyTheme}
        ref={(navigatorRef) => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
        onStateChange={(state) => {
          NavigationService.setAnalytics(state);
        }}
      >
        <AppStack.Navigator initialRouteName="App" screenOptions={hideHeader}>
          {state.token != null ? (
            <AppStack.Screen name="App" component={AuthMainTabNavigator} />
          ) : (
            <>
              <AppStack.Screen name="App" component={MainTabNavigator} />
              <AppStack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthNavigator} />
            </>
          )}
        </AppStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

App.js - render fucnction

```
 <Root>
      <StoreProvider store={store} context={AuthContext}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <SafeAreaProvider>
                <AppNavigator  context={AuthContext}/>
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </PersistGate>
      </StoreProvider>
    </Root>
```

HomeScreen.js

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { context: AuthContext })(HomeScreen);
```

But still receiving

```
Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(HomeScreen)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(HomeScreen) in connect options.
```

We have gone through the REDUX documentation:

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#using-the-usestore-hook

Simply can not work out why we are receiving this error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but this is very wrong:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { context: AuthContext })(HomeScreen);`

It looks like you're mixing up two different things. You're trying to create a context for use with your own auth state, but you're also trying to use that same context instance to override React-Redux's own default context instance.  **Don't do that!**  You should *not* be passing a custom context instance to `connect` and `<Provider>` except in *very* rare situations.

Comment: ummm, The whole objective is to get hold of the user token to render the correct view on entry. I've been following https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/. But because i use redux to manage state the guides say i should share the context in order to achieve my auth flow goal. What would you recommend?

Comment: You can use a context to pass down auth data, sure, but you _should not be overriding React-Redux's configuration to use that context instance_.  It's like you're opening a piece of mail addressed to React-Redux, replacing the entire letter with a shopping list, putting it back in the mailbox, and then wondering "why doesn't it know what the original letter said?".  Just remove all the bits defining a `context` parameter for the React-Redux APIs.

Comment: That was my initial try but i was i unable keep the token field in sync with two different contexts.  Do you have any notes on the best approach to achieve the auth flow using redux?

Comment: After reading not sure you analogy is correct - https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#using-the-usestore-hook states we can use our own defined context. So it shouldn't be a problem to create a custom one and share it amongst the application

Comment: No. You are completely misunderstanding the purpose of that "custom context" feature. That is _only_ meant for extremely rare use cases, like having multiple Redux stores used by different parts of the app. You are trying to mix two _completely different contexts_ together, _and_ overriding React-Redux's behavior, and that's breaking your application.  **Please don't do this**. You should _not_ be messing with React-Redux's context, at all. Just create your auth context, render it and pass in a value, and read that context in your own components. That's it.

Comment: @justacoder when you set the `context` argument on the `Provider` you are replacing the react-redux context -- not adding to it.  So your components do not have access to the react-redux context at all.  If you understand that then you'll understand Mark's analogy.  FYI Mark is one of the maintainers of the redux and react-redux packages so when he says that this feature isn't designed for your use case he knows because he's the one who designed it.

Comment: @justacoder You can have two separate contexts with two separate providers.  Your components get auth info from the `AuthContext` and redux info from the redux context via `connect` or `useSelector`.  The two work side by side but separately.  Though looking at this again, there is no reason for `AuthContext` to exist at all because all it stores is a function.  You can just have a hook `useAuth` to access that function and use `useDispatch` internally in that hook.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to achieve only after reading through your discussion in the comments with @markerikson.

The [example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/#implement-the-logic-for-restoring-the-token) from the React Navigation docs creates a context `AuthContext` in order to make the auth functions available to its descendants.  It needs to do this because the `state` and the `dispatch` come from the `React.useReducer` hook so they only exist within the scope of the component.

Your setup is different because you are using Redux.  Your `state` and `dispatch` are *already* available to your component through the React-Redux context Provider and can be accessed with `connect`, `useSelector`, and `useDispatch`.  **You do not need an additional context to store your auth info.**

You can work with the context that you already have using custom hooks.  Instead of using `const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext)` like in the example, you can create a setup where you would use `const { signIn } = useAuth()`.  Your `useAuth` hook can access your Redux store by using the React-Redux hooks internally.

Here's what that code looks like as a hook:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const useAuth = () => {
  
  // access dispatch from react-redux
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
      // same as in example
  }, []);

  // this is the same as the example too
  const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async data => {
        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
      signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
      signUp: async data => {
        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  // but instead of passing that `authContext` object to a `Provider`, just return it!
  return authContext;
}
```

In your component, which must be inside your React-Redux `<Provider>`:

```
function App() {
  const { signIn } = useAuth();

  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <Button onPress={() => signIn(username)}>Sign In</Button>
  )
}
```